# textarea to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, textarea

I have this code in my jsp file

```
<%  
//Instantiate MetaMap and bring the output words
coding_sugest csug=new coding_sugest();
//Get the value from the textarea
if (request.getParameter("phy_exam")==null){
    response.sendRedirect("index.html");
}

String x_value=request.getParameter("phy_exam");
csug.setPhy_exam(x_value);
out.println("<h3>"+x_value+"</h3>");
//Call to bring the list of positive words
List<String> word_suggestions=(csug.positive_words());
Iterator<String> it = word_suggestions.iterator();
//Print the list values to a textarea
out.println("<textarea name='suggest_list' rows='10' id='word_suggest'>");
        while(it.hasNext()){
            out.println(it.next());
        }
out.println("</textarea>");
%>
```

In this way I am calling my class and then a method of that class to bring me some text-values to populate them in the `<textarea>`. I want the user to modify that `<textarea>` and then create a new list with those new text-values so that I can query with the new values my database.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a form in your `jsp` file using `<form>`. Also you should add a submit button for your form. This form should be forwarded to a `java servlet` and in that 'servlet' you should add the users input into database.

Please let me know, if you have any question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? My problem is this:  I want the user to modify that <textarea> and then create a new list with those new text-values so that I can query with the new values my database. I can't figure out a way to do this.

Comment: The post has been edited. let me know if you have any question. I am not sure that I understand your problem.

Comment: hi boomz, let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: I created a servlet and i use the `request.getParameter("textarea_name")` successfully (thanks for your guidance). How do I populate the query results back to the user from the servlet?

Comment: use the following instructions:
`RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/hello.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);`
Also you can use `setAttribute` to send some data to jsp file. `hello.jsp` should be your destination jsp file.

Comment: My main problem is that on my jsp file I have the `if (request.getParameter("phy_exam")==null){
    response.sendRedirect("index.html");
}` and when I use the `request.getRequestDispatcher("hello.jsp").forward(request, response);` I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` because it's empty. Is there a way to avoid them?

Comment: You should use `/hello.jsp` instead of `hello.jsp`. Also please make sure that the `hello.jsp` file is available. If you get your answer please mark this answer as the accepted answer.